# thymeleaf -Pass id of a selected option

Tags: spring, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a select element that uses th:each to list all objects in a repository, I need to select one of them and also send to the controller the ID of the selected item.

This is a snippet of the HTML

```
<form th:action="@{/checkApiMethods}" th:object="${bmonitor}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{objectId}" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <select th:field="*{domainName}" class="custom-select mr-sm-2">
                    <option th:each="bmonitor : ${bmonitors}" th:value="${{bmonitor.domainName}}"
                            th:text="${bmonitor.domainName}">
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

I tried adding a field within the option but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need the domainName? I would argue that having it's id is more important, since you can easily fetch the rest of the information. Anyways, there are ways to do this, but seeing your entities would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this, using `jQuery` and Thymeleaf `th:data` tag. The `th:data` allows you to add any dynamic data tag to your elements. This tag will hold the id for each *bmonitor* and whenever the value of the select change, we will set the value of a hidden input, which will also be posted to your controller.

**HTML**

```
<form th:action="@{/checkApiMethods}" th:object="${bmonitor}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{objectId}" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <select th:field="*{domainName}" class="custom-select mr-sm-2">
                    <option th:each="bmonitor : ${bmonitors}" th:value="${bmonitor.domainName}"
                            th:text="${bmonitor.domainName}">
                            th:data="${bmonitor.id}"
                    </option>
                </select>
                <input name="bmonitor-id" id="bmonitor-id" hidden="hidden" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.custom-select').on('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data');
    $('#bmonitor-id').val(id);
})

// We must set the initial value, otherwise it will be null for the first option.
$('#bmonitor-id').val($('.custom-select option:selected').attr('data'));
```

Of course, you will need to add a `@RequestParam` to your controller to catch the new input.